# How to set redirects to many websites in apache with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect about one thousand links to different place and also set redirect everything other to redirect to homepage, but there is problem that I must leave my admin as it is. So I don't know how to redirect these links and also set in htaccess that I don't want to redirect nothing from /admin/.
Is there any real way? Or maybe faster?

Comment: exclude admin, redirect every thing else

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^admin - [L]` as first rule.

Comment: Use apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)  to redirect everything excluding the `admin` dir

Comment: Thanks and if i will then redirect everything else i have to insert it at the end to get it work properly? It will not redirect those i have specified where to redirect?

Comment: The rule that I suggested should be your first rule after `RewriteEngine` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this on your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin
RewriteRule (.*) newsite.com/$1 [L]
```

---

The above will redirect everything to `newsite.com` except the `admin` dir

---

Learn more about [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: thats not useable for me,i must also specify that other links where to redirect but i dont know where i can insert it in this code

Comment: sorry but I'm not following you, please update your question with some real examples